# リアルタイムでtemplate内の変数を変化させたいです

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

現在、サーバーに対してリクエストをして、サーバー側でバリデーション後エラーメッセージを返すプログラムを作成しております。
エラーメッセージをサーバーから取得した後、エラーの内容をdata.messageに格納後、console.logを用いて表示した結果、正常に値が出力されていました。

それに伴い、リアルタイムでtemplate内のdata.messageが変わると考えていたのですが、変わりませんでした。
他のプログラムでは、同等の方法を用いることで値は変わっていました。

**試したこと**
必要のない部分をすべて消去し、リアルタイムで値が変更されるか検証しました。
data.messageをv-html等の属性を用いて埋め込めるか検証しました。
data.messageを表示させる階層のパターンを複数試しました。

```
<template>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/selfIntroduction/selfIntroduction.css">
  <p>{{data.message}}</p>
  <section>
    <div class="contact__sec__wapper">
      <div class="unique contact__sec">
        <h1 class="selfIntro__title">Contact</h1>
        <label class="unique contact__form_label">メールアドレス</label>
        <input v-model="data.contactMeil" class="unique contact__form" type="text">
        <label class="unique contact__form_label">名前</label>
        <input v-model="data.contactName" class="unique contact__form" type="text">
        <label class="unique contact__form_label">メッセージ</label>
        <textarea v-model="data.contactContent" class="unique contact__form"></textarea>
        <button class="unique contact__form" @click="contactContentSend">送信</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  import { reactive } from 'vue'
  import { store } from '../store.js'
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    name: 'Test',
    setup() {
      const data = () => reactive({
        contactMeil: '',
        contactName: '',
        contactContent: '',
        message: [],
        test: '',
      })
      const contactContentSend = () => {
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('mail', data.contactMeil)
        formData.append('name', data.contactName)
        formData.append('content', data.contactContent)
        axios.post(store.state.API_URL + 'contact-send', formData).then((responce) => {
        }).catch((error) => {
          data.message = error.response.data
        })
      }
      return { data, contactContentSend }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data`に関数が代入されていますが、

```
const data = () => reactive({
```

単純に`reactive`関数の戻り値を代入しなくてはいけません。

```
const data = reactive({
```

Vue 2.xではdataは関数でないといけませんでした。
（そうでないと、各Vueインスタンスで同じオブジェクトを参照してしまうため）
3.xのComposition APIにおいては、各Vueインスタンスの生成時に`setup`関数が呼ばれるようになっているので、関数でラップしてはいけません。

Comment: 関数として定義するのではなくreactive関数の戻り値を代入するのですね。問題が解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: よかったです。解決したら回答を承認済みにしておいてくださいね。